# Hide #go_to_top icon when box is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this chat box and this go_to_top icon. Is that possible to hide the icon when the box is clicked and open, and display it again when its closed?

This is how it looks in my local host ([view extern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycl3s.png)):

[image: This is how it looks in my local host]

This my ChatBox code

```
 <section class="btn-xs bd-section-5 hidden-xs bd-page-width bd-tagstyles" id="section5" data-section-title="Section">
                <div class="bd-container-inner bd-margins clearfix">
                    <div class=" bd-layoutbox-9 bd-page-width  bd-no-margins clearfix">
                        <div type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="chatbutton bd-container-inner btn btn-default">
                            <h4 class=" bd-textblock-11 bd-content-element">
                                <span style="font-weight: normal;">Call us on</span> <a href="tel:08000125888" draggable="false">0800 0125 888</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                 <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="chat">
                            <li class="left clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-left">
                                    <img src="./assets/images/<?php echo ($cruise_avatar[0]); ?>.png" alt="<?php echo ($cruise_avatar[0]); ?>" class="img-circle" />
                            </span>
                                <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <strong class="primary-font"><?php echo ($cruise_avatar[1]); ?></strong> <small class="pull-right text-muted">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><?php echo date("h:i:s A"); ?></small>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo ($cruise_avatar[2]); ?>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="right clearfix"><span class="chat-img pull-right">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/50/FA6F57/fff&text=ME" alt="User Avatar" class="img-circle" />
                            </span>
                                <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                                    <div class="header">
                                        <small class=" text-muted"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span><?php echo date("h:i:s A"); ?></small>
                                        <strong class="pull-right primary-font">Bhaumik Patel</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo ($cruise_avatar[2]); ?>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>                        
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">
                                    Send</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

And that's it looks like this when clicked ([view extern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycl3s.png)):

[image]

I tried to hide it with jQuery like this: UPDATE it to

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".bd-layoutbox-9").click(function(){
             if ($("span.bd-icon-67.bd-icon").css("display","inline-block")){
                 $("span.bd-icon-67.bd-icon").css("display","none");
             }
             else if ($("span.bd-icon-67.bd-icon").css("display","none")){ 
                 $("span.bd-icon-67.bd-icon").css("display","inline-block");
              }
         });
     });
    </script>
```

and my span code

```
            <div data-smooth-scroll data-animation-time="250" class=" bd-smoothscroll-3">
                <a href="#" class=" bd-backtotop-1 "><span class="bd-icon-67 bd-icon "></span></a>
            </div>
```

I can hide it when Chatbox is open, but when i close it is not displayed again.

Comment: try `display: none;` in css

Comment: If jquery included, Ids and classes are right .. so this piece of code should work .. if everything is ok and still not working provide related html

Comment: please show HTML also

Comment: try this code

$(document).on("div#collapseOne.panel-collapse.collapse.in",'click',function(){
            $("span.bd-icon-67.bd-icon").hide();
        });

Comment: Try toggle like this -                 $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".bd-layoutbox-9").click(function(){
                         $( "span.bd-icon-67.bd-icon" ).toggle();
                         console.log($("span.bd-icon-67.bd-icon").css("display"));
                    });
                });

Comment: @T.Shah yes finally worked... Had to change something in class but it worked with toogle... Cheers